# Project multiple rows into a single row based on columns values in sql

Tags: sql

I would like to know how you project multiple related rows into a single row, for example, a product that comes in multiple parts will have multiple SKUs but I want to project the multiple parts into a single row.

I'm sure this is possible but struggling to define the query for the desired result.

Given the example dataset

[image]

I would like to project my result to the following

[image]

What ends up in the product code or product name columns is irrelevant, essentially I just need a single row to represent these two rows.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: This looks like a bad database design to me. Why do you have products and product parts in the column?Do you have any way to relate Prod1Part1 to Prod1, if such a product even exists?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format of data stored in ProductCode and ProductName.
According to this, you have to write appropriate expressions extracting all the useful data.
Then, of course, you have to decide what ID you will leave for new rows.

In my example I do simple transformation with substr(…) to extract necessary data,
and I use max(ID) to choose what ID will be for the row.

Test data:

```
insert table1(CustId, ProductCode, ProductName)
values
    (10, 'Prod1Part1', 'Product1 Part1'),
    (10, 'Prod1Part2', 'Product1 Part2'),
    (10, 'Prod1Part3', 'Product1 Part3'),
    (10, 'Prod2Part1', 'Product2 Part1'),
    (10, 'Prod2Part2', 'Product2 Part2')
;
```

A query:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
            MAX(id)
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            SUBSTR(ProductCode, 1, 5) = NewProductCode) id,
    CustId,
    NewProductCode,
    NewProductName
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        CustId, SUBSTR(ProductCode, 1, 5) NewProductCode,
        substr(ProductName, 1, instr(ProductName, ' ')) NewProductName
    FROM
        table1) x
```

The output:

```
8   10  Prod1   Product1 
10  10  Prod2   Product2
```

Is it clear? Ask me to improve the answer, if it's not.